# knockout.JS : Creating a grid with data grouping

Tags: knockout.js, grid, grouping, client-side

Just wanted to check this feasibility.

I have a grid created using knockout.JS. IS it possible to group the data in the grids?

The Observable array returns a lot of data. Ca we group this using a "+" in the grid?

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: You want a hierarchical grid? http://www.igniteui.com/hierarchical-grid/overview

Comment: Correct, but want to do this using Knockout.Js.

Comment: Well you'll have to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I work we implemented a grid with grouping recently using knockout and the slickgrid plugin (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) so it is most definitely possible. Beyond telling you that though I can't offer much assistance without seeing some code.